# Parse javascript string to Java

Tags: java, javascript

I want to parse js string in java, How I can acheive, I saw Rhino have parser but could not able to do. Please help me out

```
String jssting="\"if (AH.getAttributeValue(\\\"organizationTypeID\\\") == \\\"4a81e8fb-6710-4661-83ac-8012ec938aeb\\\") " +
                "{     AH.setMandatory(\\\"locationID\\\", true);     " +
                "AH.setVisible(\\\"locationID\\\", true);    " +
                " AH.setVisible(\\\"organizationSubTypeID\\\", true);  " +
                "   AH.setVisible(\\\"effectiveDateTime\\\", true); " +
                "} else {     " +
                "AH.setMandatory(\\\"locationID\\\", false);    " +
                "AH.setVisible(\\\"locationID\\\", false);     " +
                "AH.setVisible(\\\"organizationSubTypeID\\\", false);    " +
                " AH.setVisible(\\\"effectiveDateTime\\\", false); " +
                "}";
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Parse javascript string to Java*?

Comment: @KennethClark I think he wants to parse it ( to actual java code )and run the java code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320308/how-to-run-javascript-in-java-programming

Comment: this getting json string in android, In one of string this. I do not know how to js string string to get all values separately